# WinInet ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT on SSL

Tags: c++, ssl, wininet

I've wrote program that does simple HTTP POST. 
When using HTTP protocol all goes well, but when changing to HTTPS i get this error:

> ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT

```
Request("GET","www.google.pl",80,false,"/","",""); //works
Request("GET","www.google.pl",443,true,"/","",""); //ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT
```

What's funny is that i've also tried it on XP and there, insteed of `ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT` i have  (Internet Explorer 7, which can open https pages correctly)
Here is the `Request()` body:

```
string Request(const char* Method, const char* Host,int Port,bool Secured, const char* url, const char* header, const char* data)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    string ret;

HINTERNET internet = InternetOpenA("mikmas", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(internet == NULL)
        throw OpenInternetException();
    HINTERNET connect = InternetConnectA(internet, Host, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    if(connect == NULL)
    {
        InternetCloseHandle(internet);
        throw CantConnectException();
    }
    int flag=INTERNET_FLAG_HYPERLINK | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |
            INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID |
            INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH |
            INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE |
            INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI |
            INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE;
    if (Secured)
        flag|=INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;
    HINTERNET request = HttpOpenRequest(connect, Method, url, "HTTP/1.1", NULL, NULL, flag, NULL);

    if(request == NULL)
    {
        InternetCloseHandle(request);
        InternetCloseHandle(connect);
        throw CantOpenRequestException();
    }
    int datalen = 0;
    if(data != NULL) datalen = strlen(data);
    int headerlen = 0;
    if(header != NULL) headerlen = strlen(header);

    if (!HttpSendRequest(request, header, headerlen, (void*)data, datalen))
        throw CantSendRequestException();

    DWORD read;

    while(InternetReadFile(request, buffer, 1023, &read) && read)
    {
       buffer[read] = 0;
       ret+=buffer;
    }

    InternetCloseHandle(request);
    InternetCloseHandle(connect);
    InternetCloseHandle(internet);
    return ret;
}
```

I'm really confused when using WinINET. A so simple action - stupid, simplest POST over https and it's almost impossible in cpp?

Comment: At a quick glance, the use / hard-coding of `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT` seems iffy if you want HTTPS. According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384091(v=vs.85).aspx), you may be able to use `INTERNET_DEFAULT_PORT` (or the `Port` variable you pass in).

Comment: That's a solution. I've pass the port to the function but i didn't use it